# Ignore some bins from the cross coverage in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

I have the following variables:

```
bit [3 : 0] pstrb;
write_t pwrite; // WRITE, READ, UNKNOWN
secure_t psecure; // SEC, NONSEC, UNKNOWN
```

I want to define the crosspoint and cross. I also want to add some features: collapse pstrb into the 3 bins, see pstrb_cp coverpoint. I want to ignore the crosses where pwrite == READ && pstrb != 0, and also ignore the crosses where psecure == UNKNOWN || pwrite == UNKNOWN

That's the way I implement it:

```
pstrb_cp : coverpoint pstrb {
    bins pstrb_b[3] = { 0, [1 : 14], 15 };
}
apb_req_cross : cross pwrite, pstrb_cp, psecure {
            ignore_bins invld_rd_strb = binsof(pstrb_cp.pstrb_b) intersect { [1 : 15] } && binsof(pwrite) intersect { READ };
            ignore_bins invld_pwrite = binsof(pwrite) intersect { UNKNOWN };
            ignore_bins invld_psecure = binsof(psecure) intersect { UNKNOWN };
}
```

But I do not see any crosses with pwrite == READ. I also tried to explicitly define some bins I'm intersted in and ignore bins that I'm not, but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

The following lines fix this issue, but I've no understanding why the 'intersect' statement doesn't

```
pstrb_cp : coverpoint pstrb {
    bins pstrb_b[3] = { 0, [1 : 14], 15 };
}
apb_req_cross : cross pwrite, pstrb_cp, psecure {
    ignore_bins invld_rd_strb = apb_req_cross with (pstrb_cp != 0 && pwrite == READ);
    ignore_bins invld_pwrite = apb_req_cross with (pwrite == UNKNOWN);
    ignore_bins invld_psecure = apb_req_cross with (psecure == UNKNOWN);
}
```